# Stringoholics question Interviewbit, To make minimum rotations till all the strings become the same again

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to solve this DSA problem, I know it can be solved with use of kmp but I just wanna know whats fault in this code.

> Problem Description

You are given an array A consisting of strings made up of the letters 'a' and 'b' only.
Each string goes through a number of operations, where:

1. At time 1, you circularly rotate each string by 1 letter.
2. At time 2, you circularly rotate the new rotated strings by 2 letters.
3. At time 3, you circularly rotate the new rotated strings by 3 letters.
4. At time i, you circularly rotate the new rotated strings by i % length(string) letters.

Eg: String is "abaa"

At time 1, string is "baaa", as 1 letter is circularly rotated to the back

At time 2, string is "aaba", as 2 letters of the string "baaa" is circularly rotated to the back

At time 3, string is "aaab", as 3 letters of the string "aaba" is circularly rotated to the back

At time 4, string is again "aaab", as 4 letters of the string "aaab" is circularly rotated to the back

At time 5, string is "aaba", as 1 letters of the string "aaab" is circularly rotated to the back
After some units of time, a string becomes equal to its original self.
Once a string becomes equal to itself, it's letters start to rotate from the first letter again (process resets). So, if a string takes t time to get back to the original, at time t+1 one letter will be rotated and the string will be its original self at 2t time.
You have to find the minimum time, where maximum number of strings are equal to their original self.
As this time can be very large, give the answer modulo 109+7.

Note: Your solution will run on multiple test cases so do clear global variables after using them.

Problem Constraints
1 <= |A| <= 100

Input Format
A: Array of strings.

Output Format
Minimum time, where maximum number of strings are equal to their original self.

Example 1:

```
Input:  A=['a', 'ababa', 'aba']
Output: 4
Explanation: 
String 'a' is it's original self at time 1, 2, 3 and 4.
String 'ababa' is it's original self only at time 4. (ababa => babaa => baaba => babaa => ababa)
String 'aba' is it's original self at time 2 and 4. (aba => baa => aba)
Hence, all 3 strings are their original self at time 4.
```

Example 2:

```
Input:  A=[a, aa]
Output: 1
Explanation:
Both strings are their original self at time 1.
```

My approach:

```
long long int gcd(int a, int b){
    if(b==0) return a;
    return gcd(b,a%b);
}
long long int lcm(int a, int b){
    return a*b/(gcd(a,b));
}
int check(string a){
    string b=a;
    int ans=0;
    int n=a.size();
    for(int i=1;i<INT_MAX;i++){
        a=a+a.substr(0,i%n);
        a.erase(a.begin(),a.begin()+i%n);
        cout<<a<<" ";
        ans++;
        if(a==b) return ans;
    }
    return n;
}
int Solution::solve(vector<string> &a) {
    int n=a.size();
    int maxi=1000000009;
    long long int ans=1;
    vector<int>k;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        k.push_back(check(a[i]));
        //cout<<k[i]<<" ";
    }
    for(int i=0;i<k.size();i++){
        ans=lcm(ans,k[i]);
        //cout<<k[i]<<" ";
    }
    return (ans)%maxi;
}
```

It is failing for this case {aaabbaaaaaba aabaa baabbaab baabaaa aaaaababababb baab}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution would be correct if strings always reached their initial state with a fixed period, at time [*n*, 2*n*, 3*n*, ...].

But this isn't always true. For example, when the string `aabaa` first reaches its initial state, at time 4, your code assumes the sequence will be [4, 8, 12, ...]. The actual sequence is [4, 5, 9, 10, 14, 15, ...]:

```
1 abaaa
2 aaaab
3 abaaa
4 aabaa
5 aabaa
6 abaaa
7 aaaab
8 abaaa
9 aabaa
10 aabaa
11 abaaa
12 aaaab
13 abaaa
14 aabaa
15 aabaa
```

The state of that process includes the value of "i % length(string)", not just the current contents of the string.

Comment: Actually I havent assumed that, Its just that if we are rotating a string more than its own length it will only make sense to rotate just the i % length(string), also I used cout function to check it, also can you guide me how it would affect the example case I have shown, thanks in advance.

Comment: In your code, `check("aabaa")` returns 4. The second loop in `main` then computes an `ans` that is certain to be a multiple of 4. But that's not right. The actual sequence [4, 5, 9, 10, 14, 15, ...] contains many numbers that are not multiples of 4. In fact the sequence repeats every 5 steps, not 4.

Comment: Okay I got where I gone wrong thanks a lot for your help!